# Controlling a Light using two switches to function as... Sensor-Off-AlwaysOn

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I have an outdoor floodlight I'd like to switch between [Sensor-Off-AlwaysOn], which I've found a solution for on this platform, which utilizes a SPDT switch [Solution illustrated below].

However, I'd like to do this using two switches, one on my second-floor deck and the other at my basement entrance. I'd even be okay with one of my switches acting as an off-on switch.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: My question is an extension of your suggested answer, but using two switches instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the [Leviton DVS15-1LZ](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/dvs15-1lz):

[image: Leviton Switch]

> *manual-on, automatic-off, single pole, 3-way or multi-location (multi-way) when used with DD0SR switch companions or multi-sensor with two DVS15 sensors*

so I can't say 100% sure that it will do exactly what you want. But it looks pretty close, and definitely can handle a 3-way style connection, though I don't know if the wiring for that uses traditional 3-way (common + 2 travelers) or something different.